# Designing a MongoDB schema for a chat server

Tags: mongodb

I wish to design a schema for a chat server. The schema needs to support delivery and reading of messages. Each message needs to have a option of being a private or group message.

I was trying to think about where the data regarding if it has been read and delivered be sent.

In a relational database this could be set in another table. In MongoDB I could set this either in the user or the actual message json document.

If the message isn't for a specific user but a broadcast message then i presume it would be better to store the IDs of the users that have seen it as part of the json document of the message.

Does anyone know of some good example schemas that are available. I don't fully understand the best way of attacking this issue.

Comment: Do you want to specifically use MongoDB or you're also considering relational databases? It does not seem clear in your title & question.

Comment: Sorry, yes this is specifically for a mongodb database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Too long for a comment. And it kinda answers the question*)

Yeah, it's a challenging design. Also it's something we can't do for you, I'm afraid, because we don't know all your requirements, you do. However you design it, you should respect the usual mongodb guidelines. Unfortunately, they conflict with each other:

1. Don't put too much stuff into one document.

   In the classic blog schema exercise, one might be tempted to embed comments into the post document, each comment embedding its user too. This can *easily* lead to overflowing mongodb's max document size. Also it leads to write contention. Doesn't matter much for MMAPv1 engine, but matters for WiredTiger engine (which has document-level locking).
2. Do not build overly normalized schemas.

   Normalized schemas are encouraged in relational databases. In mongodb they're useless (because of the lack of joins). What you need to do is careful duplication of some data. For example, in blog/comments example, one might embed author's id/email in a comment, but not the rest of author's data (sign up date, membership status, etc.)

When I decide a place or shape of the data, I generally ask myself these two questions:

- How am I going to query this?
- Isn't this too much duplication?